# Bootstrap Package PHP Runtime Deprecation Notice

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x, realurl

Despite the wonderful announcement of the Official Introduction Package RealUrl is not working and the bootstrap package is generating these messages:

```
Core: Error handler (FE): PHP Runtime Deprecation Notice: Non-static method BK2K\BootstrapPackage\Service\CompileService::getVariablesFromConstants() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/cms/typo3conf/ext/bootstrap_package/Classes/Service/CompileService.php line 52

Core: Error handler (FE): PHP Runtime Deprecation Notice: Non-static method BK2K\BootstrapPackage\Service\CompileService::getCompiledFile() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/cms/typo3conf/ext/bootstrap_package/Classes/Hooks/PageRendererRender/PreProcessHook.php line 47
```

**Other information**

- Mac OS X Yosemite
- XAMPP for Mac OS X
- php 5.6.3
- TYPO3 6.2.6
- Bootstrap package 6.2.6
- The official Introduction Package 2.0.0
- RealUrl 1.12.8
- .htacces rewriteEngine On

Comment: Thanx lorenz!
I understand and will wait :-)
realUrl is not working under TYPO3 V7 yet. I understood from a coremember this is known and will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

You are using PHP 5.6 and obviously the extension "bootstrap_package" is not yet ready for PHP 5.6. Until PHP 5.6, calling a non-static method statically worked without a deprecation notice, but in PHP 5.6 this is deprecated and throws a warning, see http://php.net/manual/de/migration56.deprecated.php.

Since it's only a deprecation warning, this is no problem ATM and I guess it will be fixed by the extension developer.

RealURL "is not working" is not very helpful description. Please give more information about what's happening or not.

Comment: Thanx lorenz!
I understand and will wait :-)
realUrl is not working under TYPO3 V7 yet. I understood from a coremember this is known and will be solved

Comment: There is an unofficial, friendly fork of RealURL on Github that can be used with TYPO3 7 as long as there is no official release: http://github.com/helhum/realurl. The announcement of RealURL's maintainer about compatibility can be found here: http://www.dmitry-dulepov.com/2014/12/typo3-70-and-realurl.html

Comment: Thanks again. Alas there has a new problem arised: ect_emconf.php invalid and the whole site is gone .